# Understand how to decode this base64 encoded string

Tags: c#, base64, decode

I've handled base64 encoded images and strings and have been able to decode them using C# in the past.
I'm now trying on what looks to me like a base64 string, but the value I'm getting is about 98% accurate and I just don't understand what is affecting the output.

Here is the string:

http://pastebin.com/ntcth6uN

And this is the decoded value:

http://pastebin.com/Buh4xXDA

That IS what it should be, but you can clearly see where there are artifacts and the decoded value isn't quite right.

Any idea why it's failing?

```
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(Faces[i].InfoData);
Faces[i].InfoData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using the same Encoding as the sender used? Did they use ASCII and your using UTF8?

Comment: I have no idea what encoding they used, based on the answer by CJBS below it looks a bit better when using ASCII encoding, so maybe that's what he used. The competing app for this one used UTF8 and base64 for sure. So that's where I started for this one. But even with ASCII the resulting string is "damaged" a bit. See my comment to CJBS's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The string is not encoded as UTF8, but instead as another encoding. Thus the same encoding must be used to decode it.

Use the following to decode it:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

If ASCII isn't the correct encoding, here's some code that will iterate through available encodings and list the first 200 characters in order to manually select original encoding:

```
String encStr = "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";
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(encStr);

// Iterate over all encodings, and decode
foreach (EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();
    Console.Write("{0,-15} - {1}{2}", ei.CodePage, e.EncodingName, System.Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetString(data).Substring(0, 200));
    Console.Write(System.Environment.NewLine + "---------------------" + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcV5s8

Comment: You are close to it, but that's not quite the solution. If you read through the output, there many question marks throughout the result that shouldn't be there. There should not be any question marks unless it's in a description of of the watch. Otherwise it's fields and values, all of which are human readable and make complete words...i.e. your output has "shape="Triangle"widt`?"35" height="35" but it should be "shape="Triangle" width="35" height="35" - the very end of the output "</Watcj?" should be "</Watch>..."httr/?facerepo?com/" should be "http://facerepo.com/" - something is off...

Comment: Yes, I see. I iterated through all available (see fiddle link in updated answer), and couldn't see anything that worked. May I ask what the source of the string is?

Comment: What's the locale that you system is set to? On Windows: Start -> type "Regional Settings" -> on "Administrative" tab, select "Change System locale" -> what's set there?

Comment: The file is a plaintext file used by an Android Wear app to recreate watch faces on your smart watch. Until now it's been .xml but plain text inside. The competing app added protection by switching both the images and the text files into straight base64 encoding, so I was able to reverse that. This one is doing it a little different, but the result is just a plain text file, and like I said we're like 95% there as is.
I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro so your suggestion for regional settings didn't work, but I'm in the US with default settings. I do a lot of other ASCII/UTF8 encoding with no problems.

Comment: Any chance this could be Base91 or Ascii85 encodings? I know there's no native support for them but I found C# classes for both and will try this when I'm home in 8 or 9 hours. I figured by asking I may save the effort if it's clearly not either one.

Comment: So I decided to really dig in. Thanks to how Android works, I'm now pouring through his source code and he is using Base64 but obviously something is modified. I should be able to spot it in the code. Just for future reference I'll post on here when I find what it is.

Comment: Sounds good, because from a little digging, it seems that there are many different libraries on Android for encoding in Base64, from Sun's internal sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, to org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64, to the Android's android.util.Base64. And each has its own flavours. So I'd suggest getting it decoded on the Android side first, then find a C# equivalent to do it on Windows. Good luck.

Comment: He's using Android's own android.util.Base64 library, and I have the whole source code available from decompiling the app, so it should be doable. Just got to track it down in all this code he's got going on.